# MySQL query fails on syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query. It fails I think on the `CompanyBranch table_id=1122; varchar ,` statement, however I am not able to clearly identify the problem, mainly because it is InnoDB, which I lack experience with...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`firmaucet`;
CREATE TABLE `firmaucet` (
  `ID` bigint not null auto_increment  ,
  `RND` double ,
  `Nazov` varchar(50)  ,
  `Pobocka` varchar(50)  ,
  `Ucet` varchar(50)  ,
  `Kod` varchar(50)  ,
  `UcetAndKod` varchar(50)  ,
  `UcetOsnova` bigint ,
  `HomeBanking` double ,
  `ExportLastFileName` varchar(250)  ,
  `CudziaMena` smallint ,
  `IBAN` varchar(50)  ,
  `SWIFT` varchar(50)  ,
  `Pomenovanie` varchar(100)  ,
  `IDNum` bigint ,
  `BankStatement_Format` bigint ,
  `PaymentOrder_Format` bigint ,
  `SortOrder` bigint ,
  `CompanyBranch` table_id=1122; varchar ,
  `ActiveToDate` datetime ,
  `WebApiAddress` table_id=1122; varchar ,
  `WebApiAuth1` table_id=1122; varchar ,
  `WebApiAuth2` table_id=1122; varchar ,Primary key(`ID`)
 )ENGINE=InnoDB COLLATE=utf8_general_ci,DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: What is that `table_id=1122;` you keep repeating in multiple field definitions? There is nothing like that in the mysql documentation. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html

Comment: It's not my SQL so I don't really know. I suspected that to be an issue, however thought maybe it's something to do with the DB engine. Is it possibly something InnoDB specific?

Comment: I don't recognize that syntax either. It is nonsense for any MySQL storage engine as far as I know. Also there should not be any semicolon before the end of the `CREATE TABLE` statement, and `varchar` always requires a length argument in parentheses (as in your earlier columns such as `Nazov` etc.). I would guess your errors are being inserted by some automatic code generator.

Comment: Not related to your error, but if the `HomeBanking` column is meant to store currency, you should read https://dev.to/aloukissas/you-better-work-in-cents-not-dollars-ngo or https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-float.html

Comment: Yes the code comes from a MySQL rescue software after disc crash. Problem is I don't see the original, just the generated rescued SQL, so it's hard to pick up all errors it generated. Already corrected hundreds of errors. Ok I will try to go with removing the "suspicious" syntax.

Comment: No, `HomeBanking` is rather some sort of ID, definitely not currency...

Comment: Well, any data that requires you match it later with `=` would suffer from the same accuracy problems.

Comment: That is something I can't say yet @BillKarwin, the software using the DB is not mine, so I will have to see... I can only suppose the company who developed it knew what they're doing... Hopefully...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your code and it's working.
I removed the `table_id=1122` and changed `varchar` to `varchar(50)` on lines 20, 22, 23 & 24.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`firmaucet`;

CREATE TABLE `firmaucet` (
  `ID` bigint not null auto_increment  ,
  `RND` double ,
  `Nazov` varchar(50)  ,
  `Pobocka` varchar(50)  ,
  `Ucet` varchar(50)  ,
  `Kod` varchar(50)  ,
  `UcetAndKod` varchar(50)  ,
  `UcetOsnova` bigint ,
  `HomeBanking` double ,
  `ExportLastFileName` varchar(250)  ,
  `CudziaMena` smallint ,
  `IBAN` varchar(50)  ,
  `SWIFT` varchar(50)  ,
  `Pomenovanie` varchar(100)  ,
  `IDNum` bigint ,
  `BankStatement_Format` bigint ,
  `PaymentOrder_Format` bigint ,
  `SortOrder` bigint ,
  `CompanyBranch`  varchar(50) ,
  `ActiveToDate` datetime ,
  `WebApiAddress`  varchar(50) ,
  `WebApiAuth1` varchar (50),
  `WebApiAuth2`  varchar(50) ,
  Primary key(`ID`)
 )ENGINE=InnoDB
 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci,
 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b767cbee9cd46493cfe7e29ff134fb53)*